# Transconductance of MOSFET with channel-length modulation

Tags: mosfet, transconductance

As far as I understood, I think it could be derived as below.
$$
g_m = \frac{\sigma I_D}{\sigma V_{GS}} = \mu_n C_{ox} \frac{W}{L}(V_{GS}-V_{TH})(1+\lambda V_{DS})
$$
$$
= \sqrt{2\mu_n C_{ox}\frac{W}{L}I_D(1+\lambda V_{DS})}
$$
Is it correct to derive it like this?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Googling "MOSFET gm" leads me to https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee105/fa98/lectures_fall_98/091898_lecture11.pdf and there gm is the same (though they didn't include \$\lambda\$ ). So why ask here if it is so easy to find?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I also searched for mosfet gm and get the link, but I wasn't sure whether I can write gm as second line on above equation.